# Sum of two generic types in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, generics

How do I use generics in Kotlin to add two numbers of different types?
Below is my unsuccessful attempt.

```
fun <T, U>add(a: T, b: U): Any?{
    return a.plus(b)
}

operator fun <U> U.plus(b: U) {}

fun main(){
    println(add<Int, Double>(4, 5.6))
}
```

I searched for the "plus" operator in Kotlin and it seems that there is no function body when the plus operator is overloaded.

```
/** Adds the other value to this value. */
public operator fun plus(other: Byte): Int
/** Adds the other value to this value. */
public operator fun plus(other: Short): Int
/** Adds the other value to this value. */
public operator fun plus(other: Int): Int
/** Adds the other value to this value. */
public operator fun plus(other: Long): Long
/** Adds the other value to this value. */
public operator fun plus(other: Float): Float
/** Adds the other value to this value. */
public operator fun plus(other: Double): Double
```

Comment: What is your use case for this? I have a feeling this isn't possible with a single function.

Comment: There is no common `plus` function for you to use. You would have to make the function use reified types and exhaustively handle the different combinations.

Comment: All the numeric types inherit from [`Number`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-number/), whose only common methods are conversions.  So another option might be to use `Number` as an upper type bound, and convert all your numbers before adding.  Unfortunately, there's no single type which won't lose some precision; the best options would be Long (if you knew they were all integral) or Double (if there might be floats and you don't need full Long precision) before adding.

Comment: Don't know why, but I feel the complexity of using generics. Whats the use of generics when i can't write a simple `sum` function?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps.

I was able to use reified + inlined to solve the sum of two Numbers as follows:

```
fun main() {
    println("Calculating the Sum of an Array")
    (1..5).toList().customSumAll { sum ->
        println("The Sum of the Array is $sum")
    }
}

inline fun <reified T : Number> List<T>.customSumAll(h: (T) -> Unit) {
    var sum : T = getZeroByType()
    println("Zero Value of Type ${T::class} is $sum")
    for (item in this) {
        println("item is $item")
        sum = sum.plus(item) as T
    }
    h(sum)
}

inline fun <reified T> getZeroByType(): T {
    return when (T::class) {
        Long::class, Int::class, Short::class, Byte::class, Double::class, Float::class -> 0 as T
        else -> throw RuntimeException("Unknown numeric type")
    }
}

operator fun Number.plus(other: Number): Number {
    return when (this) {
        is Long -> this.toLong() + other.toLong()
        is Int -> this.toInt() + other.toInt()
        is Short -> this.toShort() + other.toShort()
        is Byte -> this.toByte() + other.toByte()
        is Double -> this.toDouble() + other.toDouble()
        is Float -> this.toFloat() + other.toFloat()
        else -> throw RuntimeException("Unknown numeric type")
    }
}
```

Comment: Used the following links to come up to this solution:
https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/how-to-write-generic-functions-for-all-numeric-types/7367
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xj45hobMI78